# How to pad a file to a desired size?

Tags: dd

I have a file that I want to pad until it reaches 16 MiB (16777216 bytes). Currently it is 16515072 bytes. The difference is 262144 bytes.

How do I pad it?

This doesn't seem to be working:

```
cp smallfile.img largerfile.img
dd if=/dev/zero of=largerfile.img bs=1 count=262144
```

Comment: @terabyte; do you want physical padding or logical padding? In other words; should the file only show a size of 16777216 (and may contain holes) or shall it also occupy that amount of storage on the disk? - BTW, choosing a `bs=1` in `dd` is in my experience very runtime expensive.

Comment: `truncate -s 16M thefile`

Comment: @frostschutz that'd be a good answer, were you to post it as an answer.

Comment: @derobert, What's with StackExchange site users posting legit, simple answers as comments?

Comment: @user1717828 not sure, probably a good question for meta.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Besides the answers to get a physical padding you may also leave most of the padding space in the file just empty ("holes"), by `seek`ing to the new end-position of the file and writing a single character:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=largerfile.txt bs=1 count=1 seek=16777215
```

(which has the advantage to be much more performant, specifically with `bs=1`, and does not occupy large amounts of additional disk space).

That method seems to work even without adding any character, by using `if=/dev/null` and the final desired file size:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=largerfile.txt bs=1 count=1 seek=16777216
```

A performant variant of a physical padding solution that uses larger block-sizes is:

```
padding=262144 bs=32768 nblocks=$((padding/bs)) rest=$((padding%bs))
{
  dd if=/dev/zero bs=$bs count=$nblocks
  dd if=/dev/zero bs=$rest count=1
} 2>/dev/null >>largerfile.txt
```

Comment: Correct. In this case `truncate -s +262144 largerfile.txt` would also be fast.

Answer (score 15):

Drop the `of=largerfile.txt` and append stdout to the file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=262144 >> largerfile.txt
```

Comment: `seek` is a right option here.

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer, courtesy of @frostschutz, posted as an answer

`truncate -s 16M thefile`

Comment: `truncate` or `fallocate`. Main differences explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1536157/432690).

Answer (score 4):

The best anwser here is Janis's (above) because it lets you forget about the current file size and pad directly to the desired size with no calculation.

It also takes advantage of sparse files, which appending /dev/zero doesn't.

The answer could be tidier though, because 'count' is allowed to be 0 and you still get the padding:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=largerfile.txt bs=1 count=0 seek=16777216
```

(Edit: this is correct for GNU dd, but the behaviour of `count=0` is platform-specific, see comments)

Comment: You are mistaken: `count=0` is unspecified, but typically is the same as when no `count` parameter was specified. More problems: `dd` truncates the file to 16777216 bytes, but if you are in hope that this creates a hole at the end, you are mistaken since you would first need to write data after the hole and later truncate it to a size that contains no data.

Comment: count=0 is nothing like specifying no count parameter. Are you saying that `dd if=/dev/zero of=somefile` is the same as `dd if=/dev/zero of=somefile count=0`? Try it.

Comment: Of course! `count=0` **is** the same as if you did not specify a count parameter at all. This is true at least for all implementations that have been derived from the original sources. Try it, it seems that you did never work with the original `dd` command.

Comment: I can't find any documentation that specifies 0 as a unique value for `count` meaning 'ignore this parameter'. Can you find any? Without such documentation, `count=0` means 'write zero blocks' and any deviation from this is a bug... (original sources or no).

Comment: Why don't you just read the POSIX standard:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html If you did read my first comment, you did know that the POSIX standard declares `count=0` to cause unspecified behavior. If there was not that single deviating clone implementation, POSIX did mention that `count=0` means infinity. If you don't know that, you should not write answers to this platform since this is for UNIX.

Comment: You're entirely right; my apologies. I only found [this unix manpage](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/dd/) which I thought was authoritative. This platform is for Unix and Linux (it's in the title) and I will continue to write answers despite having been corrected on this point, thank you.

Comment: This was the POSIX documentation from before May 2015 when the underspecified text was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `dd`?  If you want a file to have a particular (logical) length, just write a zero to the position you want.  The bytes between the previous end and the written byte will be displayed as having null bytes.  Here's an example using perl.

```
$ echo Hello > file
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 6 Apr 16 22:59 file
$ perl -le 'open(my $f,"+<","file"); seek($f, 16777216 - 2, 0); print $f "\0"'
$ ls -ln file
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 16777216 Apr 16 22:59 file
```

Why the "- 2" in the line?  The script will write a byte, so we subtract 1 to seek to the position before that byte.  We take off the other because the seek position is zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that specifically does not rely on math.

```bsh
echo 'The secret meetup location is at the seventh stairway at seven.' > message.txt
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=300 > square.rgb
dd if=message.txt of=square.rgb conv=notrunc
```

I am using this as steganography to encode a message into an image for a Su Square.

Comment: Funnily at first I had exactly this problem and this solution worked. But not even 5 minutes later I wanted to do exactly the opposite and dd didn't truncate the file, even though there were only null bytes after 2k of data it still copied the entire 2G to the output file. What exactly influences dd to truncatting the file? I also checked for a "conv=trunc", but that didn't exist. I'm a bit confused now to what exactly causes dd to truncate a file.